# Changing the resolution with Imagick

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd

Im new to imagemagick, can some one tell me how to change the image resolution using Imagemagick?

Comment: http://php.net/imagick.setresolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(new_X-resolution,new_Y-resolution);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the resolution you need to use the command:

```
-resample horizontalxvertical
```

But remember that the original resolution must be set using:

```
-density width
-density widthxheight
```

before you can use resample. Please choose this as the correct answer if it solves your doubt by clicking on the tick symbol to the left.